# How to get substring inside var in bash

Tags: bash, shell, substring

I want to extract a substring from a shell var. This is an example:

```
user@ubuntu:~$ var=$(curl -s 'https://www.youtube.com/')
user@ubuntu:~$ echo $var|grep -ob GetBrowse_rid
user@ubuntu:~$ 50000:GetBrowse_rid
user@ubuntu:~$ echo $var|grep -ob what_to_watch
user@ubuntu:~$ 55555:what_to_watch
user@ubuntu:~$ echo ${var:50000:55555}
```

I want to extract the text beetwen "GetBrowse_rid" and "what_to_watch", but for some reason my code not works

Comment: What *does* it do, and what were you otherwise expecting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `sed`:

```
curl -s 'https://www.youtube.com/' | sed -n 's/.*\(GetBrowse_rid.*what_to_watch\).*/\1/p'

GetBrowse_rid":"0xd43def10f9d14420","yt_fn":"what_to_watch
```